# How to use <windows.h> on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I have a C++ project that uses `<windows.h>` on windows. Now I need to run the program on Ubuntu. But I don't know how to make changes to the following codes that are related to the `<windows.h>`. For example, what are the equivalent of these functions on Ubuntu:

1. GetStdHandle
2. STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
3. INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
4. CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO
5. SetConsoleCursorInfo
6. GetConsoleCursorInfo
7. SetConsoleMode
8. GetConsoleMode
9. ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING

Here is my `.h` file:

```
#ifndef CONSOLE_OUTPUT_COMMON_H
#define CONSOLE_OUTPUT_COMMON_H


#include <string>
//#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#define _WINSOCKAPI_
#include <windows.h>

namespace ConsoleOutputCommon {
    void clrLine();
    void moveCursorTopLeft();
    void replaceLine(std::string s);
    void clrScreen();
    void prepareWindowsConsole();
    void clrRemainingScreen();
}

#endif // !CONSOLE_OUTPUT_COMMON_H
```

Here is my `.cpp` file:

```
#include "ms_windows_console_output_common_20200819.h"


void ConsoleOutputCommon::clrLine() {
    printf("\x1B[2K");
}

void ConsoleOutputCommon::moveCursorTopLeft() {
    printf("\x1B[1;1H");
}

void ConsoleOutputCommon::replaceLine(std::string s) {
    printf("\x1B[2K");
    std::cout << s;
}

void ConsoleOutputCommon::clrRemainingScreen() {
    printf("\x1B[J");
}

void ConsoleOutputCommon::clrScreen() {
    printf("\033[2J");
}

void ConsoleOutputCommon::prepareWindowsConsole() {
    // Set output mode to handle virtual terminal sequences
    DWORD error;
    HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        error = GetLastError();
    }

    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO     cursorInfo;
    GetConsoleCursorInfo(hOut, &cursorInfo);
    cursorInfo.bVisible = false;                // hide the cursor
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(hOut, &cursorInfo);

    DWORD dwMode = 0;
    if (!GetConsoleMode(hOut, &dwMode))
    {
        error = GetLastError();
    }

    dwMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
    if (!SetConsoleMode(hOut, dwMode))
    {
        error = GetLastError();
    }
    ConsoleOutputCommon::clrScreen();
}
```

Since I am not familiar with ubuntu, I appreciate it if you could guide me on how to fix this. When I run the program I receive the following error:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried running it with wine?

Comment: @marcinj My supervisor doesn't want to use Wine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to ifdef out all the windows code and add versions which will work under linux. For example for showing cursor - you can find code on github (always check license if it suits your needs):

https://github.com/voltengine/cli/blob/c10241a1a746d11207bc1372216e1d98fbaab201/src/util/system.cpp

```
void show_terminal_cursor(bool show) {
#if _WIN32
    HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO info;

    GetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &info);
    info.bVisible = show;
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &info);
#elif __linux__
    std::cout << (show ? "\033[?25h" : "\033[?25l");
#endif
}
```

of course you should if-def all the windows code, also headers:

```
    #if _WIN32
      #define _WINSOCKAPI_
      #include <windows.h>
    #elif __linux__
        // any linux related headers
    #endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you use an emulator (or Wine), you won't be able to use Windows headers on Linux. They're two completely separate operating systems.

One possibility would be to write your own interop layer and port the headers to Linux and them re-implement them with the desired Linux (POSIX) functions, etc.

I've done similar things in the past and have created "Win2Posix"-files which implement the functionality I required from Windows headers with Linux (POSIX) code. It's ugly, but if it's a requirement, do what you have to do.

Comment: Could you please help me with which functions do I need to change in these codes? I know nothing about Ubuntu. Thanx.

Comment: Well to be honest it's not that difficult. I don't know your codebase and I don't know what it does (frankly I don't really have the time to look at it either).
Basically all you'll need to do, is compare the functions you're using, using MSDN and then compare them to the POSIX equivalent.

If possible, use C++ std:: functions instead of OS-specific functions. That'll make your life a lot easier in future.